# Extending Case Object

Tags: scala, object, case, traits

I am new to Scala so apologies if its dumb question:
I have some common status that I won't to have enum(trait) for

```
Trait A

Object A {
   case object A1 extends A
   case object A2 extends A
val vectA = Vector(A1,A2)
}
```

I have 2 children who need additional statuses

```
Trait B extends A

Object B extends A{
   case object B1 extends B
   case object B2 extends B

val cVect = Vector(B1,B2) ++ A.vectA
def apply(status: String): C = {

cVect.find(_.toString == status).getOrElse("error")
  }
}
```

```
Trait C extends A

Object C extends A{
   case object C1 extends C
   case object C2 extends C
val cVect = Vector(C1,C2) ++ A.vectA

def apply(status: String): C = {

cVect.find(_.toString == status).getOrElse("error")
  }
}
```

Basically, I have apply method that will take string and return be Trait of Type B or C

so expecting

```
val x = B.apply("A1") to return B type enum.
```

I may be doing something completely wrong so please provide me right approach to deal with such situation

Comment: Yes Please. this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this:

```scala
sealed trait A

sealed trait ACompanion {
  def vect: Vector[A]
  
  final def apply(status: String): Option[A] =
    vect.find(_.toString.toLowerCase == status.toLowerCase)
}

object A extends ACompanion {
  final case object A1 extends A
  final case object A2 extends A
  
  override final val vect: Vector[A] = Vector(A1, A2)
}

sealed trait B extends A
object B extends ACompanion {
  final case object B1 extends B
  final case object B2 extends B

  override final val vect: Vector[A] = Vector(B1, B2) ++ A.vect
}

sealed trait C extends A
object C extends ACompanion {
  final case object C1 extends C
  final case object C2 extends C
  
  override final val vect: Vector[A] = Vector(C1, C2) ++ A.vect
}
```

Note that apart from fixing some typos, using `sealed` and creating a `trait` for the companions to reduce code duplication. The main change was understanding that `vect` will always be a `Vector[A]`; and thus `find` returns an `Option[A]`.
This is because even for `B` or `C`, you are adding extra cases but you need to also provide the original `A` cases, thus your return type will need to the the least upper bound of those which is just `A`

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/nJh23qFSQXafc0n1ogPtlg/5)*.